# An unbounded function whose directional derivatives are all zero (and implications to Euclidean horn angles)

Tags: real-analysis, geometry, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, proof-writing

Exhibit a function $f(x,y): \mathbb R^2 \to \mathbb R$ such that all directional derivatives equal $0$ at the origin, yet the function is unbounded in any neighborhood of the origin.

My work is below, to which I request verification, suggestions, and feedback, both on the proof and exposition.  In particular: I tried to write the proof so it would be succinct and intuitive, and yet still rigorous.  Was this accomplished? Could the exposition be improved?  What about the geometrical remark?

*Note: Examples and proofs exist; this question is to verify **this** example and proof.*

---

The function $$f(x,y) = \begin{cases} 
0 \text{ if } y \leq 0 \text{ or } y \geq x^2 \\
\frac 1 x  \text{ otherwise.}
\end{cases}$$ meets the criteria.

**Proof:**  By definition, $$D_vf(0,0) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac {f(hv_x, h v_y) }{h}.$$  The function $\frac {f(hv_x, hv_y)}h$ equals $0$ unless$$0 < h v_y < h^2v_x^2 \tag{1}$$ but as $h \to 0$, $$\frac {h^2v_x^2}{hv_y} = hk \to 0$$ for all $k$ and $(1)$ is not met.  Thus $D_vf(0,0) = 0$.

We now show the function is unbounded in any ball around the origin.  For all $\delta > 0, L \in \mathbb R$, there exists $(x,y) \in B_\delta(0,0)$ such that $f(x,y) > L$.  If $L \leq 0$, this is trivial; otherwise, let $x = \frac 1 {2L}$ and $y = x^2/2$.

**Remark:** This result is essentially a corollary from [Euclid's Elements III.16](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII16.html) and [III.2](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII2.html), except that Euclid uses a circle instead of a parabola.  Euclid shows if $\ell$ is a line touching point $P$ of circle $O$, and $\ell$ is not $\perp OP$, then $\ell$ also touches circle $O$ at another point $Q, Q \neq P$ [[III.16]](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII16.html) and that the segment $PQ$ is entirely interior to the circle [[III.2]](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/elements/bookIII/propIII2.html).  Thus (if we assume these results hold for parabolas as well, which they do), for any vector $v$, there exists $h \neq 0$ such that $hv$ is entirely above the parabola $y = x^2$ and therefore uniformly $0$.

Euclid also mentions, but does not explore, *horn angles*, which are curves that a. intersect $P$ b. do not intersect the circle anywhere besides $P$ and c. do not intersect the perpendicular to $OP$ anywhere but $P$.  It is such a horn angle which we find and follow to exhibit an unbounded $(x,y)$ in any neighborhood around the origin.

Comment: Your proof that $f$ satisfies the aforementioned properties is fine and succinct. A more geometric reasoning perhaps can be stated using the convexity of $\{(x,y): y\geq x^2\}$ and $\{(x,y): y\leq 0\}$.

Comment: @Mittens Thank you.  Since one definition of convex is "any line segment between two points is within the interior", then the convexity of the circle is exactly what Euclid proves in III.2, though he doesn't use that word.  I'm assuming (without proof) that applies to a parabola.  Do you feel that I'm missing something?

Comment: Correct, so, if $(a, b)$ is such that $b>0$, the segment from the origin in the direction to $t(a, b)$, $t>0$,  intersects the parabola $y=x^2$ and some $t_0>0$. Then, for $0<t<t_0$, $t(a, b)$ is in the region where $f=0$ (by convexity)